# Citroen C4 Grand Picasso 2007 Multi Function Screen C failed

Tags: citroen, electronics

I've just bought a C4 Grand Picasso, love the car, super practical and comfy.

The electronic dashboard is working fine, but the multi-function screen portion is completely blank.

So I have a speedo, rev counter, fuel gauge etc and althought the radio/cd player works I don't get anything up on the screen.

It also means I can't adjust any of the electronic settings (so the Auto Electronic Parking brake is stuck off)

Is the screen one unit or two? Am I going to have to replace the whole thing, or could it be a cable internally, any ideas?

[image: The yellow inner screen is completely blank on mine - it's not yellow either just dull grey]

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions [here](http://www.roadtestreports.co.uk/qanda/63476/) say that you may have some success pressing the button at the end of the wiper stalk or on the dash next to the display.  I'd be inclined to take it back to the dealership you purchased it from, unless it's a private seller in which case this could be the reason the car was up for sale in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, the car is from a private seller and I was aware of the problem, CD player still works so it's not a huge problem, and you get real warning lights on the dash anyway. The link you suggested I've read, but that talks about the speedo/rev counter etc, which is all fine for me, it's the nested inner screen that is an issue.

Comment: maybe disconnecting the battery for 10-20 minutes is worth a try?

Comment: @WillshawMedia - Just "talking" to a dealership may lead you to your answer. If it's something easy, you might be able to get free information from them. They want to keep good relations with their customers, even if you didn't buy the car from them.

Comment: @Mauro is that just to try and reset the system?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-translating from Slovak: ak vymenim rd4 za rd45 treba vymenit aj display

Becomes: if I replace rd4 with rd45, the display must also be replaced